# Android arrange buttons in a row

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I have some **Buttons** in a row in android like this picture.
Actually I need to add or remove the space between buttons; buttons must be steady.
I always have a button in left, a button in right, a button in center, and two other button around the center. if the screen size changes, **the gap** between buttons will change.

Thank in advance

This picture shows how it must work in small screen

[image]

And picture two shows how it will be in larger screen.

[image]

Button "1" is always Left;
Button "5" is always Right;
Button "3" is always Center;

**Question** : How can I Have Button "2" and "4" always with the same space between the other buttons?

Comment: use Space with layout_weight.

Comment: @njzk2 Space I mean gray gap in the picture(those are not a view); those are distance between buttons :)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Post code and layout files and explain more about what you want to happen "if the screen size changes".

Comment: @Squonk I Edited the Question; Is it clarify now? I have no problem with Button "1", "3" and "5"; I use **layout_alignParentLeft** and **layout_alignParentRight** and **layout_centerHorizontal="true"**

Comment: @mohammadjannesary : yes. use a Space. It is a blank view, and using weights, you can totally achieve that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I'm showing the configuration for 4 buttons. The idea is to wrap the buttons in a horizontal `LinearLayout` and to add views between buttons with `layout_weight` 1 so that these can shrink and expand when the linear layout changes size.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lh"
    android:layout_width="208dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="B" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="B" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="B" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="B" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Or, equivalently, substitute `Space` to `View` to convey the actual function of this particular View but only if using an API of level *at least 14*. [Space](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) is "*a lightweight View subclass that may be used to create gaps between components in general purpose layouts*".

Comment: Thank you; That's what I really need;

Comment: There is a widget called Space. It really is a View, but the explicit name makes it clearer why it is here.

Comment: Thanks! I will edit the answer (but note that apparently Space is available only starting from API 14).